# How to prefer `operator<<` over generic `operator T()` conversion?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overload-resolution

When both an `operator <<(std::ostream&...` and a generic conversion operator `template<typename T> operator T()` are defined, `std::cout << foo();` is ambiguous. Is there a way to make that resolve to invoking `operator <<`?

Shortest working code:

```
#include<iostream>

struct foo {
    int x;
    template<typename T> operator T() { return static_cast<T>(x); }
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, foo& f) { return out << f.x; }
};

//std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, foo& f) { return out << f.x; } // doesn't help

int main() {
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `operator<<` isn't even viable there, since `foo()` is an rvalue and your `operator<<` requires an lvalue argument.

Comment: [This code works](http://ideone.com/dbiawM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own operator is not viable as it takes the `foo` by non-`const` ref which the temporary cannot bind to. Thus, the post-conversion overloads are considered in the first place.

Changing its declaration to

```
friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const foo& f) { return out << f.x; }
```

fixes the issue. Now your operator is the better match as it requires no conversion.